# Raw housing stock of particular city

Tags: economics, us-census, historical

I want to get the raw number of units of housing stock that there is in a particular city in month X of year Y (even yearly data would be fine). [This place](http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=bkmk) shows yearly stock from 2010 onwards. [Here](https://www.census.gov/hhes/www/housing/census/historic/units.html) shows data for every 10 years. This link

```
www(dot)washingtoncitypaper.com/blogs/housingcomplex/2014/10/24/d-c-s-housing-stock-in-charts/
```

makes me think there should be more yearly data since this has 2013 data.

Is there anywhere I can find a more comprehensive data set?

Answer (score 2):

The US Census collects housing data in multiple instruments. The one I'm most familiar with is the American Community Survey (ACS). ACS data is released in 1-year and 5-year tabulations (and until 2013, in a 3-year tabulation). In order to mitigate sampling error, the 1-year release only covers geographies with population >= 65,000, which means that it only has "city-level" data (Census summary level "place" or 160) for about 2% of US cities. At the metro level, the 1-year sample has a bit over half of the "core based statistical areas" (CBSA, a catch all for metropolitan and micropolitan areas). So if you can deal with those constraints, you could consult [table B25001 for all CBSA in the US, ACS2014-1 year.](http://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/14_1YR/B25001/0100000US.31000.003)

There is another product with which I'm less familiar, the [American Housing Survey](http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/ahs/). The AHS is conducted every two years and includes data down to the metropolitan level.  Here is the [download page for the 2013 AHS metropolitan summary tables](http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/ahs/data/2013/metropolitan-summary-tables---ahs-2013.html)

Base housing units are also counted for the decennial census, of course, but since timely data is part of your request, that's just a footnote.